# Creating a list of links

Tags: php

I want to create a PHP file that checks the current directory for any files ending in .jpg, and then I want to generate a page of links to all of those files.

```
<?php 
$files = glob("./*.jpg");
if ($files) {
foreach ($files as $file) {
?>
 <a href=<?php echo $file;?>"></a>
<?php }
?>
```

This is what I have, and it doesn't do anything, and I'm not quite sure why. I'm quite new to learning php, so I'm not fantastic at it at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your anchor element needs to have some child element(s) inside of it,  or else nothing will be displayed in your browser:

```
<?php 
$files = glob("./*.jpg");
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<a href="'. $file . '">' . $file . '</a>';
}
```

You also do *need* the `if` statement,  as `glob` simply returns an empty array if no files are found, but you can add it back in if required.

Comment: you're also missing a curly bracket. (hey @tim-cooper)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly bracket. Add another `}` to the end of your code. Open it up and view the source and you should see all the links.